Negative active power readings?
I am using a Fluke 434 Power Quality Analyser on a balanced load, on the supply side of a CNC machine. I am acquiring active, reactive & apparent power, see graph below.

Would I be right to say that the spikes of negative Active Power are due to the stored energy in the various motor coils when they are turned off?

No, when they are turned off, they are not connected to the line, so you wouldn't see that.
It's more likely that it occurs when a motor temporarily over-speeds (say, upon sudden removal of a load) and the control circuit must slow it down.

So this could be caused by the changing the direction of one of the axis for instance?

Sure, that would do it, too.
